# Play multiple tracks from one MediaPlayer instance

Tags: android

I'm working on a looping app to loop tracks once they're recorded. I want to be able to play more than one track at the same time.

Is there any way to do this with a single MediaPlayer instance, or do I have to allocate a new MediaPlayer for each track that I want? Are there performance issues with either solution?

Comment: good question .